# Choosing between Stack Overflow and Software Engineering

Tags: support, faq, site-recommendation

Suppose you have a "borderline subjective" question, and you're not sure if you should post it to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) or [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). How do you decide? What's the best default option if you really can't decide?

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225)

Comment: Other questions about SO vs. PSE: [What's the difference between Stack Overflow and Programmers SE?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68384/whats-the-difference-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-se) and [its duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88684/stackoverflow-vs-programmers-stackexchange).

Comment: Related: [On which Stack Exchange should questions about asymptotic runtime complexity analysis be asked?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228577/163250).

Comment: This needs to be updated, to include *codereview.SE*.

Comment: see also: **[Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773)** at MSE. @Anony-Mousse - this MSE guidance covers CR.SE and generally is much more up to date "That's the most clear cut, on Code Review you share _working_ code for peer review..."

Answer (score 430, accepted):

If it is related to coding or tools, it should be on [Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

If it's directly related to the [Systems Development Life Cycle](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bb/Systems_Development_Life_Cycle.jpg) (except for troubleshooting, writing or explaining specific code), it should be on [Software Engineering](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

From the [Stack Overflow FAQ](//stackoverflow.com/faq):

> Stack Overflow is for professional and
> enthusiast programmers, people who
> write code because they love it. We
> feel the best Stack Overflow questions
> have a bit of source code in them, but
> if your question generally covers …
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - matters that are unique to the programming profession
>
> … then you’re in the right place to
> ask your question!

---

From the [Software Engineering FAQ](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq):

> #### What topics can I ask about here?
>
> Software Engineering Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professionals, academics, and students working within the systems development life cycle who care about creating, delivering, and maintaining software responsibly.
>
> #### If you have a question about...
>
> - software development methods and practices
> - requirements, architecture, and design
> - quality assurance and testing
> - configuration management, build, release, and deployment
>
> ...then you're *probably* in the right place to ask your question.

**Some questions,** even if they appear to fit into one of the above categories, **may still be off-topic** or a poor fit for Software Engineering:

- explaining, writing or debugging code
- providing support for tools or products
- finding or recommending products or services, including tools, libraries or  packages, programming languages, books, scholarly papers, tutorials, articles, or blogs
- career or education advice
- legal advice or aid

However, if the question is closed as "too broad" on Stack Overflow then it's highly likely that it's also too broad for Software Engineering. The same rules apply on both places.

If the question is closed as "primarily opinion based" on Stack Overflow then it's fairly likely that it'll be closed for the same reason on Software Engineering. While Software Engineering does allow more leeway in this area, it's not a free-for-all.

- See also: [What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](//meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7182)

Comment: Interesting, there are still some borderland issues that is not covered though. Suppose you have a specific problem and are looking for suggestions on proper designs (eg. you want to apply some design pattern like structrue on a specific problem to make it reusable or extensible). I believe this would fit best in Software engineering, but according to the guidelines about it _could_ also fit under stack overflow here...