# Should this question be on Programmers?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

I ran into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764512/how-to-count-the-number-of-positive-bits-in-a-type-of-java-in-o1). I then suggested that it should be on Programmers rather than on Stack Overflow. From [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254570/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange) question:

> In a nutshell, Stack Overflow is for when you’re front of your compiler or editor working through code issues. Programmers is for when you’re in front of a whiteboard working through higher level conceptual programming issues.

The OP didn't provide any non-working code that would need fixing, he is asking what method should be used, however someone said that it shouldn't go to Programmers. Why is this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How is that a "higher-level conceptual programming issue"? He's looking for an algorithm to perform a very specific calculation.

But regardless of whether or not it might be on-topic for Programmers, *algorithm questions are not **off-topic** for Stack Overflow!* Just because a question *might* be on-topic in multiple places doesn't mean you must spend your days shuffling stuff around until you find the *perfect* place; it's a waste of time for all involved, and there may not be one.

See also: [Respect the community – your own, and others’](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/)

Answer (score 2):

No, it's just a bad question.  It needs to be specified (much) further.  Programmers is good for a lot of "soft" questions about design and best practises and whatnot.