# Where or How to ask "Best way to implement something"

Tags: discussion

I am wondering where is a good place or how is a good way discuss what is the best way to implement something (algorithm for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour) is a great place to ask questions about algorithms. Just be sure to take a quick read though the [help](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help) section to ensure your question is on-topic and of good quality.

Comment: What is the difference between stackoverflow and this community?

Comment: @ZilbermanRafael: whiteboard vs. keyboard.

Comment: [Choosing between Stack Overflow and programmers Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254570), @ZilbermanRafael