# A suggestion to keep theoretical questions rather strictly focused on coding

Tags: discussion, scope

I asked a question about how the LSTM regularization parameters are used.

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65877836/what-is-the-conventional-ways-to-regularize-rnn) was closed based on a claim:

> I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the help centre but about ML theory and/or methodology

---

However, there have been many theory questions asked on the site with many upvotes.

For example,

- [What are metaclasses in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python?rq=1) (6015 upvotes)
- [What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters?rq=1)
- [What is the intuition of using tanh in LSTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40761185/what-is-the-intuition-of-using-tanh-in-lstm)

---

Here is a question been closed for the same reason but it received 147 upvotes, indicating that people found this question useful and meaningful. Yet it was closed because it did not follow the rules exactly. It is interesting that it is under the same tag Machine Learning.

- [Why must a nonlinear activation function be used in a backpropagation neural network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782071/why-must-a-nonlinear-activation-function-be-used-in-a-backpropagation-neural-net?rq=1)

---

This question is posted not to criticize a specific high reputation user. It is rather to find a better way to improve the network. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. Theoretical questions should not be closed. Maybe the guidelines can be improved.

Comment: High rep generally correlates with experience with the site and how to curate it for it to be the most useful to future readers. It's a decent correlation, but it's not *great*, admittedly. But that's a completely separate issue from what looks to be the main point of your post. Your original question doesn't look to be asking about a very concrete programming problem as far as I can see, it'd probably be more suitable on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) which is (I think) much more geared towards ML theory than SO, which is more for specific programming issues.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this question. [854 votes but closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480650/what-is-the-role-of-the-bias-in-neural-networks?rq=1)  Apparently, StackOverflow has many experienced users and it is where people find reliable answers fast. A recommendation would be to adjust the question guidelines since there plenty of theoretical questions without any programming specific question from Python tag. I mean the objective of the site is to promote the computer community and this recommendation doesn't violate this vision. Thanks

Comment: There are thousands of questions asked each and every single day.  Just because some that deserve closing get overlooked does not mean that your question should also be overlooked.  Just because questions asked a long time ago were allowed to stay open by the standards as they were then, does not mean that your question is also judged by those old standards.

Comment: Well, I guess the question shall be changed to a suggestion to keep theoretical questions rather than question the reps.

Comment: 'Maybe the guidelines can be improved or the network should be managed by professional managers', OK, how much are you willing to pay, up front, to submit a question?  I'm thinking a lowish value since most questions are easily-answered mega-dupes and trivial homework-dumps.  How about $10?  I guess that PayPal would do.

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, I am willing to pay. I believe you are an expert in your field and you don't like questions that are simple to you. I must emphasise they are simple because you are experienced. There are uses of different levels, and the best way to evaluate one's learning is to teach others. You can just ignore the question instead of judging it, there are others who find this question shall be answered.

Comment: @Leo so..... quite a large team of professional managers would be required to cover questions about the design, code, test, debug etc. of the more popular languages.  You may be willing to pay $10 per question, but I doubt that general, enthusiastic support for such a system would be forthcoming.  It's not SO, and I doubt it would be financially viable:(

Comment: @MartinJames So I have rephrased the question. This would be a suggestion to keep theoretical questions that are new to the site (questions never been asked before). Give simple questions a room to breathe, if it is not good, it will sink to the bottom anyway.

Comment: 'you don't like questions that are simple to you' not quite.  If an inexperienced developer has fallen into one of the black holes of development, but has shown some effort to climb out, that's fine by me.  OTOH, 'please help' code dumps that could have been debugged with a couple print statements, (or, shock-horror, an actual debugger),  are indeed annoying.  IMHO, a very large set of such questions are not authored by their OP - a poster who has designed, coded, tested and debugged nothing.

Comment: @MartinJames Ok, we are kind of off the topic here. I just feel that [question like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61931629/overfitting-in-lstm-even-after-using-regularizers) can be really useful, especially the answer from Abhishek Verma  who shared personal experiences which are pretty useful. If we can refer back to my question, we sure can find the definitions of the 5 parameters on Keras website but there aren't any guides on how they are used. If one shares his or her experiences, that would be beneficial to less experienced.

Comment: Please understand that there are many computer-sciency/theoretical-related sites on SE: [cs.se], [cstheory.se], [stats.se], [ai.se], [softwareengineering.se], and [many more](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name). SO has been considered for *practical* programming issues.

Comment: Your first two examples are not "theory questions", but pretty good questions within the scope of SO.

Comment: @ead What if I rephrase my questions as to "what are activity regularizer and kernel regularizer？“, making it the same way as the first two examples. Would it be treated differently?

Comment: Again, that does not sound like a question about programming at all. There are theoretical questions about programming (like the one about an OOP pattern you included in your examples, even though it has nothing with machine learning to do) but questions about theories from other fields obviously are not acceptable.

Comment: @Leo It is not how the question is asked, but  the topic of the question: asking "what is a sledgehammer?" would be off-topic. Asking about metaclasses and syntax of python is on topic.

Comment: @desertnaut the answer to that question isn't "no" though.

Answer (score 5):

No.

(gasps of surprise form the folks I just spent 2 hours arguing this with in [SOCVR](https://socvr.org))

Purely theoretical questions are off-topic.  As stated in the [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) wiki, there are better Stack Exchange sites for it.  The vast majority of ML theory questions fit under this case, and are rightly removed (although it would be more helpful if they were migrated).

Now, theory **with an implementation basis** is, in my opinion, on-topic.  Many decisions made in ML code are entirely based on "what can the computer do efficiently?" which can give rise to implementation questions (when phrased as a narrowly tailored ["what does this code do"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278797/how-to-deal-with-questions-of-the-type-i-dont-understand-how-this-code-works)) that are on-topic.  I find your third example to be an example of this.  Of course, the accepted answer doesn't go into why [tanh is an implementation trick that leverages efficient bitwise math](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4371008), but it is.

How to apply said theory is obviously on-topic.

Your question is a ["what is the best way to"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265854/where-or-how-to-ask-best-way-to-implement-something) question and thus off-topic for soliciting opinions - completely separate from any ML issue.

Comment: In the end we know we will assimilate you. We're not surprised ...

Comment: I still disagree with "ML Theory as cv reason" though, for reasons explained here.  There's a lot of implementation-based theory in ML.

Comment: I is possible to escape from SOCVR, though your ship will need to be warp-9 capable.