# What are the differences between Stack Overflow, Software Engineering, and Code Review?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I do not understand what the differences are between [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) , [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). All of them seem to be the same thing: talking about programming. So I do not understand where to post this or that question.

Comment: Cross-meta post: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598)

Comment: see also: [Choosing between Stack Overflow and Programmers Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254570/839601)

Answer (score 142, accepted):

I'll not repeat the excellent answers on [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) here, but just to summarise it for your 3 choices:

- CodeReview: Your code works but you'd love to hear how it could work *better*
- Stack Overflow: You are trying to get your code to work, or make your IDE sing, or that library dance, but need some help. You are hacking but not quite hacking it.
- Software Engineering: You are working out an *approach* to coding, and are still *at the whiteboard* working it out.

Answer (score 35):

Stack Overflow: "My code is not working as expected."

Code Review: "My code is working, but I think it might be improved, please critique it."

Programmers: "I don't have any code yet but my idea needs help."

Also see: [Choosing between Stack Overflow and Programmers Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254570/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange)

Comment: Not wrong, but this discriptions of Programmers.SE leaves room for all those 'homework' questions that start with: I've got this question and I need an idea (and code) on how to solve it. Because of that, I like Martijn Pieter's better.

Comment: @GolezTrol I disagree. You have to have an idea. If all you've got is a homework question, you haven't got an idea. For homework specifically, you'd need to have some kind of thought on an approach and need to be able to identify where you're confused. Just as, "Give meh teh codez" questions don't fly on StackOverflow, "Give meh teh algorithmz" questions wouldn't (or at least shouldn't) fly on Programmers.

Comment: Your description of SO is not quite right. No surprise really, since half the network apparently has no idea what SO is. That's why we have such a big problem with it at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow: "My code or my application doesn't work as I expect and I can't figure it out".

Code Review: "My code works (or at least I think it does) but there's something still off about the way it looks or behaves and I'd like a second opinion".

Programming: "I have a conceptual question about a design pattern, or a best practice, or about working in a coding environment in general, that isn't about real code so much as about doing the job of a coder".

Comment: Your description of SO is not quite right. No surprise really, since half the network apparently has no idea what SO is. That's why we have such a big problem with it at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow: Analysis of existing code or reasoning about the rules of our favourite programming languages (also, by extension, some fault-finding if you're good and lucky<sup>1</sup>)

Code Review: Review for your existing code

Programmers: Anything more abstract that relates to our jobs

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> SO is *not* "fix my codez"/"my codez dont work". It is *not*, primarily, a fault-finding website. It is *not* a code debugging service.</sup>