# Confusion on what types of questions belong on stack overflow

Tags: discussion, scope

I was reading over [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266341/what-are-the-differences-between-stack-overflow-programmers-and-code-review?cb=1) and I was a little confused on exactly what kinds of questions Stack Overflow concerns itself with. The highest rated and accepted answer describes SO as this: <

> You are trying to get your code to work, or make your IDE sing, or that library dance, but need some help. You are hacking but not quite hacking it.

Fair enough, so it seems like the type of question that SO wants to deal with are specific issues regarding pieces of code or programming related software. Further down there is another answer that says this about SO:

> My code or my application doesn't work as I expect and I can't figure it out

Seems fairly similar to the accepted answer, but beneath it is a comment (that has been upvoted numerous times) that says:

> Your description of SO is not quite right. No surprise really, since half the network apparently has no idea what SO is. That's why we have such a big problem with it at the moment.

Furthermore, as per SO's [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), SO seems to allow questions regarding *a specific programming problem.*

I want to be a user who contributes to SO's knowledge base and am afraid that I'm part of the "half the network" that doesn't know what constitutes a good question, or even what belongs on the site. Therefore, of the users above, who is right?

Comment: There are people that feel that *debugging your code* should be off-topic. Debugging *without enough context* certainly is.

Comment: That's fair enough, but in that case what does _a specific programming problem_ refer to? I apologize if I sound ignorant.

Comment: The majority of questions are along the lines of *how do I achieve X in language Y*, often quite specific. Or questions if *foo* is a keyword, or why using *bar* instead of *baz* affects performance so much.

Comment: @davidicus Basically, it refers to "I want to frob the gurgle. I have tried the following... [short, self-contained example] but it got the following error [complete traceback]. What should I do?" That's a better question than "Here are my three hundred lines of code. I get an error saying 'your variable foobar is not defined' How can I fix it?" Sometimes the distinction can get blurry. (In particular, "debugging service" complaints often refer to errors that turn out to be missing semi-colons and the like)

Comment: @davidicus A good rule of thumb is "Other people may have your problem. No one else will have your code." For instance, some users put something like  "KeyError on line 373" in their title, even though (usually) no one else will have the exact same error on the exact same line. That's treating SO as a debugging service since it is a problem specific to one's *code*. Instead, questions should be specific to one's *problem* ("I want to reverse a dictionary so its keys are values and values are keys").

Comment: @DavidRobinson yes and no. Asking 'why do I receive a key error when I do XYZ' would be reasonable, even if it's specific to your code, because it's still describing a general problem, and could be useful to others to avoid repeating your mistake. But I agree, just putting 'KeyError' in your title tells us nothing about what you're problem is, and is just general debugging service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're both right.

Ultimately, we want to be a repository of useful programming knowledge.  The problem with highly-specific troubleshooting questions is that they're highly-specific to the asker, and may not be useful or interesting to anyone else.

That's why we have a thousand different questions about Null Pointer Exceptions, describing a thousand different, highly-specific scenarios, but we also have a generalized "What is a null pointer exception, and how do I fix it?" question that covers all of the scenarios in a canonical way.

There is, of course, the possibility that one other person will stumble onto your very obscure question with a posted solution, and it will save him hours of troubleshooting time.

Naturally, your question still needs to be written in a way that it's answerable, whether it's highly specific or general.