# where to ask what?/ What to ask where?

Tags: feature-request, questions

I came across a question on the stack Overflow part of the site, in which was off topic and should have (probably) be asked in another section of the site.

I was just wondering if there is a page of:

**'Where to ask what?'** or **'What to ask where'?**

Which would possibly help others decide 'Where should I be asking this question', instead of having to point them to the correct exchange time and time again ourselves.

Would anyone know if there is something like this already on the site, rather than going to each subsection of the site to see what's on and off topic?

A situation such as  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26382593/3913686) apparently isn't suited to the mathematics stack exchange?

Comment: @gnat I was thinking more a small page to direct people to the correct pages, instead of always just posting a question randomly somewhere to **get the direction they need**. I know the example I gave isn't great, but other questions might be better/more beneficial if posted in a different area of the site

Comment: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773)

Comment: cheers @gnat, that was the sort of thing i was looking for. I'll defo be linking that more often. It would almost be worthwhile adding that to the 'Help' section

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation

Comment: The question you linked would be off-topic everywhere.

Comment: This is actually a really good feature-request, though it should be on meta stackexchange.  We should have just one place, though I'm thinking that Stack Exchange.com fills that role.

Comment: @LanceRoberts, I agree it would be beneficial for quite a few new users.

Comment: edited question looks like a duplicate of [What are the differences between Stack Overflow, Programmers, and Code Review?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266341/what-are-the-differences-between-stack-overflow-programmers-and-code-review)

Comment: I may have asked this question on the wrong meta, but I feel this would be very beneficial to *all* exchanges - not just SO/ Programmers/Code Review @gnat.

Comment: I suggested a new duplicate mainly because [its answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266344/839601) refers these _all_ exchanges and is not limited to only SO/P.SE/CR - in that sense, duplicate title is slightly misleading, answer is much broader than question

Answer (score 2):

The closest you'll probably get is

[Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday).

It lists all the sites in one place, though a modification of it that helped askers find the right site to ask on would be beneficial.