# What kind of questions belong on Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation

I have found that Stack Overflow is for posting questions about how to improve code; also, Jamal over at Code Review has been very helpful. This is my original question:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67343/correcting-user-input-to-meet-a-specific-requirement-for-hangman?noredirect=1#comment123288_67343

and I have revised it to make it clear. Now, because of confusion on this site and the question being down voted, it has banned me from asking questions on Stack Overflow. Jamal, a moderator on CR, was trying to help me migrate the question to Stack Overflow but it failed because of this ban. So I think one of the only ways to fix it is to fix my post rep on this question because deleting it does not help. In addition, this post will contribute to other noobs having similar issues. ("This should be a wiki example :)")

A note to new users, for a list of sites and what to post per the sites go to this link: https://stackexchange.com/sites#

This is the new problem: it says I have asked 3 question but I only see 2, so the third one came from another site.

[image: "You have reached your question limit" error]

[image: list of my current questions]

Comment: Read the help/faq.  It looks like you haven't yet.

Comment: Take the tour, and please open [tag:python] and check the existing questions.

Comment: Sites like *Yahoo! Answers*, *Quora* and *4chan's /r/ and /b/ channels* are some places where you can ask questions without having to bother whether they are grossly off-topic in each of them. If you wish to ask in the SE network, though, it helps to see what kinds of questions people are asking in each site. You asked a programming question in Super User, and this site usage question has been migrated from SO. How would you react if I called your home phone number asking for pizza delivery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the differences between Stack Overflow, Programmers, and Code Review?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266341/what-are-the-differences-between-stack-overflow-programmers-and-code-review)

Comment: To be fair: trenten is having a harder time than necessary here. Not only is the example question put on hold for the wrong close reason given the code review context in my opinion, but then he is in the first link also given bad instructions on what to do to get help (post this meta question rather than go to the help center first). Of course one can apply a little restraint first and reason to look for a FAQ section, but still... its not exactly pretty how we got here.

Comment: @Gimby not to mention the whole "help center process" is not really that intuitive/clear anyways.

Comment: all i realy need help on was how to fix my code and it works fine in python. i first want to know why the question was put on hold for broken code when the code works fine with python 3.4.1. and now i have more negative rep by posting this question that was vauge i was just asking for help with my original question and where do i go to get help on what i can post on what sites. MY CODE IS NOT BROKEN and this is a duplicate question i stated that allready. fml

Comment: i am also getting the feeling that the people putting my stuff on hold have not read the entire question and they probably get rep for putting me on hold. so i get nowhere and they get whatever. also i have read the tutorial on how to post a question but not what question go where and i see questions relating to who is better on starwars or unicorn stuff but this is put on hold. ????

Comment: @trenten Nobody gets rep from putting questions on hold. This question you initially posted on SO was off-topic there so it was rightly closed there for being off-topic. You then asked it here but it is too broad. Are people supposed to repeat to you word by word what is already in the site's help? If there's a specific part of the help that confuses you then ask a question about that specific part. (Also, the downvotes on Meta do not affect your reputation.)

Comment: Ooh shouting! That's going to earn you a couple of -1s.

Comment: ok about to delete this i guess i accidentaly posted to code review when it should have been on stack overflow i guess. now how do i migrate it?

Comment: Can this be reopened or converted to a wiki i could write. i need this bad rep reposed. i was mis-directed to post this as a help question here.

Comment: @trenten You're not gaining or losing any rep for questions posted on Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: i have edited with new pictures but it says i am banned for posting 3 questions which have recieved bad rep but there are only 2 question on my stack overflow site and one has no votes.

Comment: @trenten I'm writing up an answer here. Give me a bit.

Comment: @AnnaLear thanks so much also i don't want to keep posting here i know it can be bad to drag this on. i will wait. But thanks again for helping me.

Comment: Here is a tip, based on some of your older posts and comments, and this post. Use sentences. Use some punctuation. Use some capitals (where appropriate, not On Every Word or TO SHOUT). Bad grammar and punctuation are downvote magnets; using proper grammar invites a reader to react and comment on your content, rather than its form.

Comment: @trenten It's not that you can't post here for help with the site, it's that you're asking about things listed in the help center. As far as I can tell, you are genuinely confused about how the site works, and that's okay! It's fine to get confused, and it's great you're trying to understand. :) You apparently received some incorrect advice telling you to ask on Meta before you were being told to check out the help center. On that note, do check out the help center, especially the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it could really help you out.

Comment: (cont.) Also not that, as Jongware said, grammar and punctuation are important here. You don't have to be perfect, but doing your best to capitalize the first letter of a sentence and use proper punctuation goes a long way to making your question easier to read and understand. And whatever advice Anna Lear gives in their answer, it'd be a good idea to try to follow it- The diamond there indicates a mod, and Anna actually works for SE, if I remember correctly.

Comment: thanks @Kendra i have fully figured out the mistakes i have made. right now i am trying to fix this mess of down voted questions i have posted in search for the help i was seeking the site list page helped the most. now i just need a perfectly asked off topic question migrated to stack overflow from code review but i am banned because of the now 2 down voted questions one of which has an accepted answer. and this question.

Comment: Not a problem, happy to help. And, it looks like Anna's got your back, so you should be able to recover if you follow all this advice. Just remember on your next question, anywhere on the network, the points you've learned here. :)

Comment: Another quick heads up for you, @trenten: Putting "thanks" at the end of your question is considered fluff and should be removed. I know it seems polite, but on SO, it's considered unnecessary. I don't think it's likely to get you tons of downvotes, but it's nice to know, in case you're confused as to why anyone would remove it.

Comment: @Renan Posting on this website is not a phone call.  It does not intrude into your life in any way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry about the closure on this question. I think a few folks here missed what you were actually asking. For someone new to the network, "Stack Exchange" is quite likely synonymous with "whatever Stack Exchange site I used", which is fair enough. Just to be clear: this *is* the right place to ask questions about Stack Overflow, about your account, general support questions, etc. I would recommend spending the time making sure your question is clear and easy to read. That will maximize your chances of getting a good response from other users.

Having said that...

The principal difference between Code Review and Stack Overflow is that the former is for reviews of code that *already works as intended* whereas Stack Overflow is all about code that doesn't work. "My code is not broken except that I have a bug" is a weird sentence. Either it works and has no bugs... or it doesn't quite work and doesn't do what you want.

There is a rather detailed breakdown of the computer science-related sites we have and what their scope is: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in).

As far as the question rate limit goes, you did ask three questions - one of them was *this* question that was migrated by a moderator from Stack Overflow here to *Meta* Stack Overflow. I disassociated it from your profile, so it no longer counts as one of your questions on Stack Overflow. I'm going to migrate your coding question from Code Review to Stack Overflow in about an hour (gotta wait for a cache to expire; long story). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks so much @AnnaLear you have helped so much. i am new to python programming almost to the end of my first semester. To me broken code meant- run time error or it does not run . you have fully clarified that in this answer with the intended to work as expected.  thanks for the ones who have helped me out here. i think i have this place figured out now. :) "Hopefully".

Comment: @trenten: **Use proper English.**  Have someone review your posts if you're having difficulty doing that.

Answer (score 4):

The question where I posted this answer was closed as a duplicate, but I believe it can still be useful here.

## Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow

[Stack Exchange is a network](https://stackexchange.com/tour) where many communities such as Stack Overflow are connected.

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) is one of the 142 Q&A websites of Stack Exchange, for enthusiastics and professionnals programmers.

Follow these two links - they contain the answers to many questions.

## Stack Overflow and other programming communities

If you are hesitating between [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and StackOverflow, there is a simple way to decide :

If your question is about coding, go on SO. If it's about concepts linked to programming, go on programmers.SE.

### Links helping to know which site is for what

[Choosing between SO and Programmers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254570/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange?s=1%7C1.7590)

[Which computer science or programming SE community should I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

## Meta Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow

Meta sites are here to answer questions, requests and bug reports about the site itself. So [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) is here to answer questions about Stack Overflow.

## Meta Stack Exchange and Meta Stack Overflow

Even if Stack Exchange is the network, it has its own meta. It is used to answer questions that apply to the whole network.