# Are requests for code improvements of running code on-topic on SO?

Tags: discussion

I'm especially asking for OP's like this one:

[Frequency Count of Number in an array in C is this code effective and efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33473716/2003898)

as I flagged this post as "it should be migrated to code review, sicne it is asking for review without stating any special problem" but the flag has been rejected and I'm wondering if those posts are therby ontopic on SO?

Comment: I hope not.  There is enough online competition crap on SO as it is:(

Comment: I haven't even bothered opening it, but I would bet all my tins of dog food that the poster has given no criteria for 'effective' or 'efficient'.

Comment: Yup - I had a look.  DCV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because a question may be on topic on another site does not mean it is off topic on stack overflow. So the fact that a question asks for a code review is not by itself enough reason to close the question.

In this case though the question is clearly too broad/opinion based for SO so I'm slightly surprised the migration was rejected. Especially since the question is essentially asking for a code review and nothing else.

Perhaps the Code Review mods looked at it and said that they did not want it for some reason?

Either way in this case I agree with you, I'd have thought a migration to Code Review appropriate as well.

Comment: ".. does not mean it is off topic on SO .."? Much to my surprise, I received a similar miffed reaction when voting to close [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/110855) as "off-topic because code reviews are best asked at Code Review" from one of CR mods (200_success). My response: "But the code does not contain errors!" ... and I was pointed to the Help Center. But SO *is* for "a specific programming problem" and "a practical, answerable problem .." which in my view **excludes** code reviews. We even have a special subsite for it!

Comment: .. (after looking for references) Does Adam Lear's (SO moderator, 18.7K) [opinion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275116/2564301) not trump 200_success (CR moderator, 78.4K *on* [*CR*](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9357/200-success)) on policies related to SO? I quote: "The principal difference between Code Review and Stack Overflow is that the former is for reviews of code that already works as intended whereas Stack Overflow is all about code that doesn't work."