# How do I settle where my question belongs?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I'm working on a custom implementation of a Bootstrap carousel in WordPress.  The problem is, I posted the question once to Stack Overflow and had it deleted after about a week because I thought it might have better belonged on WordPress Development.

However, after reading through their site rules a bit more, as well as doing more research on the issue I have, I'm no longer sure about the most productive place to post my new question.

It is a coding question, which is why I posted on Stack Overflow to begin with, but I'm looking for some specific insight into how I should make a WP_Query, such as if I need pagination and how I should express the number of posts per page after fetching all of them.

Things that are a bit specific to WordPress regardless but not about themes or anything either.  I know that Stack Overflow has a tag for WordPress too, but I'm still unsure.

Are coding question only to be posted on Stack Overflow or can they be asked on other sites like WordPress Development if it is specific to WordPress implementation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What kind of questions belong on Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275082/what-kind-of-questions-belong-on-stack-exchange-and-stack-overflow)

Comment: Can you link the deleted question? Your question doesn't sound off-topic, perhaps a bit broad though, so it might've been deleted for another reason than you think

Comment: If in doubt you can also ask at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation for site recommendations

Comment: And to answer the question _Are coding question only to be posted on Stack Overflow_, that's a solid _No_, many sites on the network answer coding questions, and some non-SO sites answer nothing else (e.g. [codereview.se])

Comment: "if I need pagination" sounds rather squishy. In other words, it sounds like you want someone to make a decision for you, when the honest answer is "it depends"...

Comment: @Erik Indeed; [here's the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58626646/wordpress-with-bootstrap-carousel-will-not-slide-to-show-grid-of-older-posts). It was never closed, nor did it even receive any flags recommending closure. It was only deleted by a moderator because the OP essentially requested this via a custom flag (proposing to ask a similar question on Wordpress.SE instead, and since we don't allow cross-posting...).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I understand but my point is that pagination is a functionality in Wordpress.  I have read about what pagination does, since I had my previous post deleted, but I don’t know if using it would do anything given how Bootstrap works.  I tried it once before and couldn't tell.  Would that still read as "squishy"?

Comment: Bootstrap has nothing to do with pagination. Bootstrap basically makes things pretty. You can apply Bootstrap CSS to WordPress' pagination. Asking a question about how to do that would be on-topic (if not a duplicate). Asking whether you *should* paginate or not is where the "squishiness" comes in.