# My question was closed as a duplicate despite explicitly rejecting the solution given at the other question

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433121/difference-between-allocation-and-explicit-size-in-fortran) I made has been recently closed arguing it was a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337658/fortran-90-differences-in-declaring-allocatable-array).

**This is not a duplicate:** Even though the situation is exactly the same and the question may seem to be the same, the fact that the answer chosen is specifically the case I was already discarding means my question was not answered there. What am I to do if the answer that the OP has chosen does not address what I was looking for, even if the questions seems to be the same? Is there another way I don't know to re-kindle a question that is not mine to ask for more detail that the OP didn't care for?

**This *might* be too broad:** we have been speculating about it with another user in the comments, but speculation is really of no use here. I really remain unconvinced about this: I do not think it is that broad, since it is about two specific definitions. It might have aspects that are dependent of the compiler, but that is also the case of a lot of other issues that can also be answered by clarifying this, informing the most common case, mentioning other possibilities, etc. This is part of the question.

If it was the case that the people who know about this consider it **that** broad, I would like to hear an argument for this so that I could learn from it, and maybe then re-formulate the question in a better way.

Comment: seems like you are going to get down-vote for this post on that question.

Comment: It would be nice to see the gold user who used the dupehammer power to close weigh in on this.

Comment: Hopefully you're get some feedback from domain experts in the comments - the question has already been through the re-open queue and unanimously was voted to leave closed... you should probably leave a comment to the dupehammer closer with your concerns

Comment: @Nordico (no idea about FORTRAN - just generic SO comment...) to get this question to be re-open-able by broad community you need to address main concern covered in comments - language specific part is duplicate, the rest is implementation specific and require either specific compiler information OR possibly clear explanation of why you looking for this (but you'd need to spin your question in some other direction like "how to detect if difference X impact my code" to be more concrete).

Comment: Thanks to all; I may be wrong, but I still think people downvoting me are not really looking at my points; I feel like I'm dealing with bureaucracy. I will be editing the post again to explicitly include every information I've been able to gather here; will it then be  passed again through the "reopen system"? (All I know about how the reviewing system works is what @JonClements said; I didn't even understand most of the jargon, I had to google what a dupehammer is and even now I'm not sure I understand it; I posted here because thats what I found googling what to do in this situations)

Comment: Related question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215241/asking-again-a-question-for-which-the-accepted-answer-is-incorrect

Comment: @Nordico the feeling of dealing with bureaucracy is something you get all time with Stackoverflow since they started blocking all the interesting questions in favour of specific per-person question (making the website much less general purpose)

Answer (score 29):

Since I don't know any Fortran, I won't try to judge whether the question is truly a dupe of the other.  However, I can say that they look very, very similar.  In the future, if you come across a similar question while researching your problem, don't be afraid to put that in your question and explain why that doesn't solve your problem.  That will help people understand why it is different.  Once people can see that it is different, they can vote to reopen.  No need to bring it up on meta.

However, your question is a bit broad as written right now.  I count 7 question marks in that second paragraph.  That is 7 different questions you are asking.  I know they are all related, but that is still a bit much.  Many of those questions could be answered with a yes/no answer, but to really answer those questions properly would probably require examples and at least some amount of explanation.  Each.  And all that would require at least a blog post, if not a couple of them, which makes it too broad.  Also, asking for "best practice" will almost always get a question closed because it invites a lot of opinions over what the "best" practice is (and there is a specific close reason for opinion based questions).

Overall, your question may or may not be a dupe (I am not qualified to answer that).  But even if it isn't, it isn't at a point that is ready to be reopened either.

Comment: Ignore the specifics of fortran: the first question is "what's the difference between orange and apple juice?"; the OP chose an answer that said "the color" and the discussion ended there. My question was "what is the difference between orange juice and apple juice, **other than the color**?". In a sense they might be broadly the same question, but I insist: what am I supposed to do if I cared for other differences? Too bad, the question has already been asked? What if the answer that satisfied the OP does not satisfy me? Wasn't that other question actually **broader** than mine?

Comment: @Nordico First, there may be more answers on that question that may satisfy your question (again, I didn't look because I know I won't be able to understand if any other answers may help you or not).  Second, if you want to know about the difference between apple and orange juice other than the color, narrow it way down and be specific.  Like what is the difference between apple juice and orange juice in terms of the nutritional value?  Full stop.  If you want to also know about the differences in chemical composition, that is a separate question that should be a separate post.

Comment: @Nordico Also, asking for which tastes better (analogous to "best practice") is just off-topic.

Comment: There are two answers and both point to the same thing. I guess having many questions may seem overwhelming, but I did it to actually direct a little bit and be "less broad"; yo do recognize that my question almost by definition more specific that the one I was referred to and was deemed as ok, right? Sorry to seem pedantic, but I'm starting to get really frustrated here...

Comment: I posted in stack overflow after reading stuff like [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254570/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange), [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266341/what-are-the-differences-between-stack-overflow-programmers-and-code-review) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in). From one of them: "and you really don't have to worry much if you post a good question on the wrong site, we can move it to the right site automatically"...

Comment: Ok, stack overflow considers "best practices" that are specifically about code implementation as too subjective? Ok, I have no problem with that; my question had other parts but fine, move it to the appropriate place. My question was not moved, it was closed down. And I am complaining to you in 500 character batches because there is not one human giving me any reasons for being "unanimously voted to leave closed" and all I have is a sign that says my question is a copy of another question which, despite similar wording, doesn't have the answer to what I ask for.

Comment: I know you have nothing to do with this and I appreciate you answering to me. But I honestly don't know what I am to do. I posted this here because of what I read [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57104/how-to-appeal-a-closed-question) and instantly get told I shouldn't do this. I think I have never been disrespectful or anything, I am really trying here, but I really really feel like I am not being listened...

Comment: @Nordico Sorry this is kinda frustrating.  Part of the problem lies in how the reopen queue works.  All it asks is "Should this post be reopened?"  My answer would be no, because of the reasons stated above.  As far as migration goes, we can only migrate it if it would be on topic on the target site.  Does this fit Codereview? Nope.  Programmers?  It's probably more on-topic there than here, but it would probably still get closed as too broad or opinion based.  Also, migration doesn't happen unless it is voted to be off-topic here but on-topic there.  Dupes don't fall in that category.

Comment: Just because the question is not appropriate to SO does not mean we can (or have to) migrate it for you somewhere appropriate. Especially as many questions are simply inappropriate for *all* SE sites. Suggestions to implement a migration-path to yahoo answers, [while popular](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99467), were never implemented.

Comment: @Nordico If you feel migration might be appropriate, flag for mod attention and explain what you need and why you feel it is appropriate.  Bringing it up on meta wasn't wrong, just may not always be necessary.  Sometimes you do need fresh attention to your question and meta is the way to get it.

Comment: @Deduplicator I am not saying that you **have to** do anything. I am trying to explain the frustration of trying hard to find and comply with the rules and criteria and being at every step rejected **without any explanation** (at least not from the ones voting for the closing) of why and not knowing what else to do.

Comment: "But even if it isn't, it isn't at a point that is ready to be reopened either." You may have a point, but that just doesn't feel right. If someone puts in the effort to write a genuine question or answer, it shouldn't be closed unless it's for a **valid reason**. There should be at least some basic respect for the author's time and efforts. By that I mean it should be re-opened and the author should have the opportunity to address the claims of "too broad".

Answer (score 9):

Before I start, I'll say that I both wrote the accepted answer of the duplicate target and engaged in the "too broad" discussion in the comments.  I didn't vote for closing or re-opening.

I agree that the older question does not clearly prompt the same answer coverage as this new one.  I would not have voted to close as a duplicate, although I may well have pointed to this question in a comment to avoid repetition.

That said, the [revision at the time](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31433121/1) does make it very tempting for this closing.  You start by asking much the same question.  In one question we have

> In which situation would we use the first version?

and in the other

> What are the practical differences [between the two]?

If we know what the differences are, that's informing our choice of when to use one form rather than the other.  I didn't think it appropriate, for the level of the person asking, to cover what became your subsidiary questions.  After all, "is the second version even an allocatable array?" suggests a very low level of understanding where the points would be far too arcane.

Coming to your complaints about how my first answer wasn't of interest to you.  I can understand that.  However, let's look at the bit you say you don't care about.  A simpler example question is:

> What is the difference between these two arrays
>
> ```
> integer :: a(5)
> integer, allocatable :: b(:)
> ```
>
> except for the fact that one is an allocatable array and one is of fixed size?

At the level of the Fortran language there really is nothing to say there.  Indeed, the only thing of interest is that one may be dynamically changed.

You have a number of questions:

- Do they draw on different memory stacks?
- Is one faster than the other?

These are totally outside the scope of the Fortran language.  While it's implementation detail and there may be some overlap between very common systems/compilers there cannot be a universal answer.  Certainly for this second question.

- Does it make a difference if the arrays need to be passed onto another subroutine?
- Does it depend on how the variable is used, in a predictable way?

Any difference comes from their declarations: one being allocatable the other not.

- Is there a best practice associated with choosing which case to use?

When one is better than the other will be subjective except for the situations when only one can be chosen.

- Do the subroutines have different "interfacing requirements" ?

This is an interesting question, but again any answer really comes down to the fact that one is allocatable, and in many situations there would be no difference.

To summarize, many of your sub-questions are too broad or subjective as they depend on other use cases or just aren't defined by the Fortran language.  The part of the duplicate question you wish to ignore is such a significant component that it doesn't make sense to consider the question without it - except in ways which are implementation-specific (too broad).  Even if the duplicate were wrong, the question as a whole is still off-topic as too broad.

Comment: (0) I feel you have taken phrases like "your answer not being of interest to me" the wrong way. I am by no means trying to imply your answer to the other post was not useful, interesting, helpful, etc. Apparently it was exactly what the other guy was asking for; It was just the "short" way I had to explain in less than 500 and a little upset, that it was clearly not the answer to my question, so the question cannot be the same.

Comment: (1) Extracting my question from the context is kind of unfair. Anybody looking at the revision that actually reads the whole thing can see that the first paragraph explicitly says that I am talking of a case in which there is no size change and this is the first thing I say. I later set it to bold to make it stand out, but the phrase was there from the beginning and though I added by sheer luck (it almost felt unnecessary at the time), it makes it clear from the chosen answer in the old question that we were not looking for the same thing and the answers will not show the same content.

Comment: (2) I don't understand why all that is next are "reasons why the question is broad" and not actually the answer for my questions. For example: I do not know much about how the heap and the stack are administer, I mentioned it because I had problems with this in the past and I was told it had to do if the variables were allocated or explicit but not much more. If this was the reason, I wanted to know more about it. I am asking because I know this kind of things exist and are important because they can later bite you in the back, but I don't know exactly how they work...that is why I'm asking...

Comment: If the question was just "what other difference exists between the two declarations in **this post**?", would that have been ok? What if I was the first person to ask the question and not the other guy; if I had commented on you answer "Yeah, I already knew that, but what are those practical differences you are ignoring"? Then you would have closed the thread for being too broad? You would have stopped answering? You can really say nothing of interest/objective value about those "practical difference" you mentioned on that other question?

Comment: 0) I'm not offended by your remarks: I answered the other question in what I thought was an appropriate way for the audience, and I couldn't expect it to hold for everyone else.  1) It's reasonable to look at the question as it was at the time it was closed, especially regarding the nuances around emphasis.  Yes, the content doesn't change much between revisions, but people don't also interpret things exactly as the author intends.

Comment: 2) Without explicit focus from the question on which aspects are of interest, an answer must consider an awful lot of things.  If you want to know about specific things (including a "I don't understand the area - what should I care about?") then you should guide the potential answerer.  Having so many of those points in one question is too daunting.

Comment: I ignored in that other question the implementation bits mostly because it wasn't relevant, but also because I have nothing useful to say.  "It depends on compiler, compiler version, compiler options, hardware, size of n, system settings, perhaps something non-deterministic" really adds nothing to the answer.  Yes, I could have commented in reply that that was why I'm ignoring it - and that could have been helpful to you.  Other people may have more things to say on the implementation level, but I haven't.

Answer (score 4):

I am the one who closed the question. At that time there was no indication at all it is not an exact duplicate of the other one. Please read your [original revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31433121/1) again. There was no indication you actually knew anything at all about their difference.

Now, even if some fine details may be missing in the answers in the other question (@IanH made some fine advanced  points in his comments) they can be added to the original question pointed by the duplicate.

Anyway, if someone else feels like having a relevant non-duplicate answer to your question, he can nominate it to reopen, I will not block it, I will even support it and not wait for 5 votes. I will however not reopen it myself alone.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have read the original revision, and I insist that the first paragraph is what sets them apart: I am explicitly discarding the given answer (all given answers) to the  "duplicated" question. I later added the bold, but the first paragraph has always been there.

Comment: How can they be added to the original question? I honestly don't know how to ask for further information in some else's question, specially if it has already been answered. Commenting in chosen answer? But what if that person who gave that answer doesn't know the extra information and some else does? Those people are not going to detect my comment.

Comment: Well you can comment under the answers just a small clarification suffices. You cannot ask a full question there. By added I meant added by the answerer, not by you.

Comment: Ok, but that is what I'm saying. I cannot ask the same question because it would be duplication, but in the answers of that question it is implied that there is more to know. How can I ask to the community what is that, without opening my own question? Not what can be done, what can **I** do to ask for more and not just to the one user who gave the answer?

Comment: Well you could have started by asking the answerer to expand his answer in a comment. It is better to have the information in one place. Anyway, as I said, if someone fells like answering your question instead of expanding answers in the old question, he can vote for reopening. I didn't see any re-opening vote yet. I am also not the only one with the gold Fortran badge, others can revert my closure if they believe I misused it.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, this question is not a very good one. Even no longer being a Fortran specialist, I fully agree with @francescalus remarks.

But (still IMHO) it is not a duplicate of the former, since you explicitely say that you want to know whether there are other differences than the ones discussed in former question's answers.

My conclusion is that is may deserve to be down-voted (and it has already been) because neither itself not its possible answers will greatly increase the knowledge base of SO, but it should not be closed as duplicate.