# Add Software Engineering to the list of alternative web sites on the on-topic page

Tags: feature-request

At the bottom of the **on-topic** page ([Help Center > Asking > What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)) there is a list of alternative web sites provided for questions that are off topic for Stack Overflow:

> If your question is not specifically on-topic for Stack Overflow, it
>   may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. If your question
>   would be of interest to …
>
> - Computer enthusiasts and power users, ask on Super User.
> - Professional system and network administrators, ask on Server Fault.
> - Users of TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and related typesetting systems, ask on TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange.
> - Database administrators and professionals, ask on Database Administrators Stack Exchange.
> - SharePoint enthusiasts, ask on SharePoint Stack Exchange.

Can [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) be added to that list? Perhaps something like:

> - Software architects and designers, ask on Software Engineering.

It's not uncommon to find reasonable questions relating to software design that are off topic for Stack Overflow, but would be fine on Software Engineering.

Comment: What did SE meta say when you suggested this feature there?  I'm not in favour of any migrations except those performed entirely by OP's, ie. they search tmeselves to find a site where their Q. is on-topic, copy/repost their question onto that site and immediately delete their question from SO.

Comment: @MartinJames skomisa isn't suggesting a migration path, but merely a passing remark in the Help Center.

Comment: @duplode see also  [Help center doesn't include a link to SE.Programmers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326410/839601)

Comment: There are a lot of questions about these kind of sites to add to the list. I believe I myself might have asked one at some point in time. I believe the general answer is that this list is based on the number of migrations that happen(d) in a certain period of time. So if there would be a massive increase of migrations to Software Engineering it might warrant a spot in the list in favour of SharePoint?

Comment: i would like code review to be on there, but if we keep adding them we'll run out of space. a search bar or something would be good though. so you can search for the other site you are recommending

Comment: @Scriptable folks at CR.SE seem to oppose being there, see eg [Be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253975/839601) and about 20 questions linked to it

Comment: @gnat yes I would only recommend when on-topic for there, I understand their frustations though, if its off-topic here or too broad doesn't mean it fits there instead

Comment: @gnat Interesting. I assumed placing a link there would be considered less invasive than an hypothetical migration path -- I stand corrected.

Comment: @duplode Exactly so; all I am suggesting is _"merely a passing remark in the Help Center"_. I cannot understand how my post can be construed as being about migration.

Comment: @gnat I accept that my post is similar to the one you link to [Help center doesn't include a link to SE.Programmers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326410/help-center-doesnt-include-a-link-to-se-programmers). However, I consider that post was also incorrectly closed as being a duplicate of a question on migration, as the OP there pointed out. Nether that post nor mine are about migration.

Comment: The migration to the Softwareengineering SE, and showing it between the alternatives sites are obviously too different things to make this question a dupe. I suggest Reopen.

Comment: @skomisa: Stack Overflow users have a very poor track record recommending Software Engineering as an alternate site for users' questions.  The site scope is not difficult to understand; it is for questions directly related to the Systems Development Life Cycle, except for coding help, which Stack Overflow already serves very well.  Yet we get a steady stream of recommendations for questions that are off-topic on Software Engineering for the same reasons they are off-topic on Stack Overflow: Too Broad, Unclear, etc.

Comment: Consequently, there's some reluctance to add Software Engineering to the list of alternate sites, for the same reasons that Code Review is reluctant to add theirs.  People having questions they want to ask generally need to bring real questions to the table, not shop them around hoping to find a site that will tolerate them.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Your comments actually form a response/explanation for the issue I raised, and I think it would be helpful to post them as an answer instead.

Comment: these comments merely repeat points made (and much better explained) in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326414/839601) in duplicate question

Answer (score 7):

I disagree.

The veteran users and moderators of Software Engineering barely know what's on-topic on that site (and it keeps changing over time). So it is next to impossible for regular users of that site to know what's on-topic there. Meaning it *will* be impossible to know for SO users with no experience of that site. And so we will end up migrating things Software Engineering regards at garbage, which isn't helping anyone.

Overall, migrating questions to other SE sites is often unsuccessful. I believe the current stance for SE is that migrating is an obsolete feature that we should avoid and phase out.

If not for that, there's at least 10 other SE sites that also could be added to that list. Code Review, Comp Science, Electrical Engineering and so on. And some sites like CR does not even want that to happen.

Comment: I would prefer code review being added since alot more question fall in line of *"Can someone optimize this code or tell me optimization tips?"* than what OP was talking about.

Comment: @Pygasm Code Review doesn't *want* most of those questions, though. That's why they're not on the list.

Comment: Assuming we migrate at all (which I still believe is an obsolete feature), then  other sites that could work for migration would be Computer science, Electrical engineering, Arduino, Code Golf, Software Recommendations, SO in Spanish, SO in Portuguese, SO in Russian. But we'd have to grind it through their respective meta.

Comment: I agree in spirit, but I take some umbrage with "migrating is an obsolete feature".  *Some*.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Are there any sites that want questions from SO? We should just get rid of migration if other sites don't want questions from SO and SO users want to migrate but are dissatisfied with the current migration options.