# Is Stack Overflow an appropriate website to ask about system design questions?

Tags: discussion, design, site-recommendation, stack-exchange

I’m planning to practice some system design questions asked during tech interviews, and I’d like to get reviews/opinions on how I’d design some systems from the Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange community if I can.

Can I post these questions on Stack Overflow, or would some other Stack Exchange site be more appropriate for this?

Comment: You might want to check out [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), but I'm not completely familiar with their scope. You'd want to check out their help center and Meta before asking there.

Comment: The general rule of thumb between Stack Overflow and Programmers is: "if your problem is on the whiteboard, ask on Programmers. If your problem is on the keyboard, ask on SO."

Comment: ServerFault might potentially be appropriate, too.

Comment: @gun2171 So _that's_ when I ask on Programmers! Been here 4 years and never worked that out.

Comment: See, every single user of "Programmers" seem to have their own personal definition of what the site is for. And almost every question there gets closed, because nobody knows what's on-topic. I wouldn't recommend anyone to use that site for any purpose.

Comment: IME what @Lundin says is true... it seems very hard to ask opinion-based, design/planning questions anywhere on SE....

Comment: @HC_, that's because the site is set up to encourage users to select the "correct" answer that best solves their problem.  Opinion-based questions make it hard to determine whether or not the problem has actually been solved, and it ends up being more of a beauty contest than a study group.

Comment: @gunr2171 That's a catchy rule. Do you have a reference to something official?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254571/1043380

Answer (score 19):

In general design includes opinion, taste (or lack thereof) and many, many options with no definitive answers.

That does not fit SO.

However, if during the creation of a design a question arises that has a definite answer (How accurate is DateTime.Now?) you could ask that as a separate question on SO.

Comment: Design is a so-called [wicked problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wicked_problem). It's not so much that answers are opinion-based, although many are. I would say that the wicked nature of design questions makes them difficult to answer. "[It depends](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22it+depends%22+%5Bdesign-patterns%5D)" shows up a lot in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

These questions are generally fine on SO, *if* you manage to narrow down the scope to a specific problem. You can't ask fuzzy, broad questions to invite for some sort of open discussion, or ask for people's opinions.

When looking through the posts that have the [design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design) tag, they generally don't seem to be all that well-received, likely because they were too broad or invited opinion-based discussions.

You can ask more detailed design questions, I think questions like for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29650374/get-all-static-variables-of-a-class-without-reflection) are perfectly fine, where the OP has narrowed down the design problem into an appropriate format for SO.