# Isn't it better to be as specific as possible when asking design questions?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, answer-quality

I lurk [design-patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-patterns) and see a lot of questions of the type "Is this a good design?" and then there's an abstraction of the problem using ClassA/ClassB/Foo/Bar/etc. or animal classes Dog/Cat/etc. See [more examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dog%20%5Bdesign-pattern%5D). In addition to the abstraction, one sometimes writes, "my actual problem is more complex..." etc. The problem with answers is that they tend to generate more heat than light on the subject. [Is an "infinite" iterator bad design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622591/is-an-infinite-iterator-bad-design/2622605#2622605) is a good example, in my opinion. The question is interesting, but it's nearly impossible to answer it definitively. Even the accepted answer says "it depends on the context" (which wasn't really specified in the question).

Shouldn't there be [advice on how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for design-related questions to avoid "general" cases, that using abstractions of the problem (instead of the gory details) leads to answers with "it depends" in them?

I suspect people don't supply details for several reasons:

- proprietary information;
- insecurity about their own design;
- it takes longer to describe the details (software constraints are complex);
- gamification of SE, a.k.a. quest for Internet Points, a.k.a. the TL;DR factor: one is more likely to get answers and up-votes if a question is simpler.

Design can be a [wicked problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wicked_problem), which essentially means that any decision you make to **solve** the problem has the potential to **change** the problem (implying you didn't understand it fully at the start). I realize all these things make design questions hard for SO, as discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290723/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-system-design-questions). But I think one stands a better chance of getting good answers if the questions are fully qualified (and not abstracted). As for most complex questions, a TL;DR summary is recommended at the start.

Another way to think of this: [the phrase "it depends" in an answer about design](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22it%20depends%22%20%5Bdesign%5D%20is%3Aanswer) (as of this edit, **there are more than 600 answers like this!**) is a symptom of a question lacking constraints or context.

Comment: _Shouldn't there be advice for design-related questions to avoid "general" cases, that using abstractions of the problem (instead of the gory details) leads to answers with "it depends" in them?_ - Are you asking if it's OK to close these with the "Too broad" option?

Comment: This is related, if not a dupe: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256663/is-a-question-about-design-patterns-too-opinionated-for-stack-overflow

Comment: @rene Related because design is complex, but not a dupe IMO. The "opinion" part gets confused with the "it depends" part.

Comment: @BSMP I'm not asking about closing, as it's a touchy subject. Nobody would close that "infinite Iterator" question, because it was too broad (even though "it depends" was edited into the accepted answer, after all the heat generated in the comments). I'm posing the question about specific Help advice for asking design questions (edited to put a link to the help page).

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the [tag statistics](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/design-patterns/topusers).   Voting is quite extraordinary, I don't know any tag that comes close.

Comment: @HansPassant What would be a sign of a problem in those statistics (is there a discussion about this)?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252866/17034