# Difference between Stack exchange and Stack overflow and programmers?

Tags: discussion, support

I just wanna know the difference between Stack exchange and Stack overflow websites.what is difference between posting questions either one of this link?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow

[Stack Exchange is a network](https://stackexchange.com/tour) where many communities such as Stack Overflow are connected.

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) is one of the 142 Q&A websites of Stack Exchange, for enthusiastics and professionnals programmers.

Follow these two links - they contain the answers to many questions.

## Stack Overflow and other programming communities

If you are hesitating between [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and StackOverflow, there is a simple way to decide :

If your question is about coding, go on SO. If it's about concepts linked to programming, go on programmers.SE.

### Links helping to know which site is for what

[Choosing between SO and Programmers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254570/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange?s=1%7C1.7590)

[Which computer science or programming SE community should I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

## Meta Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow

Meta sites are here to answer questions, requests and bug reports about the site itself. So [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) is here to answer questions about Stack Overflow.

## Meta Stack Exchange and Meta Stack Overflow

Even if Stack Exchange is the network, it has its own meta. It is used to answer questions that apply to the whole network.

Comment: Also see [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) on the Big Meta.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I hope you don't mind me adding it in the answer.