# Can we discuss design problems on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Many times we have problems that are related to designing aspects (I mean software architecture-related). Although these are opinion-based questions, but they help a lot in designing a software better where you can understand the usefulness of design patterns and their practical usage.

And such questions are common occuring, e.g.:

- When should I use micro-services over SOA?
- Should I use factory design pattern or abstract factory?

Such questions would generally be closed as they are opinion-based, but can be good resources for software architecture aspects.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254570/3001761