# What is the purpose of [discrete-mathematics]?

Tags: discussion, tags

First of all, this is in no way a burninate request. I just want understanding.

As I understand it, StackOverflow is a Q&A website for programming. According to this high-level definition, questions that do not directly involve programming should be directed to other sites on SE.

Questions about discrete mathematics are usually not questions where you are [sitting in front of an IDE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254571/6387757), so I am confused as to why these questions are not redirected to Mathematics SE or maybe even Programmers SE. I understand the correlation between discrete math and programming, but when you look at [the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discrete-mathematics), most of these questions have no programming language associated with them and are therefore not directly related to programming.

So again my question is: Why are these questions accepted on StackOverflow?

Comment: On StackOverflow you can also ask language-independent algorithms. If the algorithm is related to discrete mathematics, I don't think the tag hurts.

Comment: @Oriol This makes sense. Although this tag does seem to attract questions which clearly are not intended to be used in any program, I guess this happens with all tags on SO sometimes. ([Help me with my homework!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37783623/logic-conversion-from-english))

Comment: @Oriol the tag hurts when people use it as premise to ask off topic questions. Case point [I want to delete the \[internet\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255169)

Comment: @Braiam There are also off-topic questions with [[tag:javascript]], but that doesn't mean we should remove the tag.

Comment: @Oriol that's so strawman argument that I feel that either are missing the point or are trolling me. If a tag consist only of not-even-programming questions, do you think that the tag makes no harm?

Comment: You guys can discuss removing the tag, but I want to remind everyone that it is not the main desire of my question

Comment: An example of a fitting question would maybe be something concerning a [De Bruijn sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/deBruijnSequence.html). I know they are quite useful in hashing sets, and there is certainly some mathematical rigor to them. [Here's an example question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365562/de-bruijn-like-sequence-for-2n-1-how-is-it-constructed) I think the tag can apply to some similar kinds of questions, and could be useful for the mathematically inclined on SO.

Comment: @Braiam I wasn't trolling. Sure, there are some off-topic questions. And others would be on-topic on other sites too, there is overlap. But having a glance at the tag, a considerable number of them seem acceptable.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely don't think it's fair to say that literally every question in the tag is off-topic. I was just noticing that many of the questions in this tag are off-topic and they didn't seem to be getting much attention like what I'm used to in tags like python or javascript.