# Is this discrete-mathematics problem fit for the site?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

I was recently reviewing posts on triage, and I stumbled upon this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77876897/knights-and-knaves-logical-equivalences-problem-for-discrete-structures

> [image]

I immediately thought it had nothing to do with programming, and flagged it. However, when I checked the answers, a high-rep user answered it. It was also tagged with [discrete-mathematics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discrete-mathematics). But, the description of that tag says:

> Only questions about software development related to discrete mathematics are on topic. Discrete mathematics is the branch of mathematics concerned with discrete phenomena – as opposed to continuous phenomena like geometry, real analysis, physics, etc. Typical discrete math topics are discrete probability, combinatorics, graph theory, algorithms and complexity, but also matrices, difference equations, recurrences.

I don't believe this fits the criteria, but there's a chance this problem could still relate to programming.

I found [What is the purpose of [discrete-mathematics]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326384/what-is-the-purpose-of-discrete-mathematics), but it has no answers.

Is this question fit for Stack Overflow?

Comment: Doesn't look like a programming problem to me. The answer also doesn't include any programming. It's a common logic puzzle, but not programming related at all.

Comment: "_a high-rep user answered it_" a user with high reputation posting an answer has nothing to do with a question being on-topic. Just ignore the reputation of the answerers and assess the question with your best judgement.

Comment: Having something to do with a tag reasonable for an on-topic question doesn't make it an on-topic question. See [ask], [help/dont-ask] & the closing & privilege documentation. PS That use of logic is discrete math but the term isn't typically used to include logic.

Comment: I guess the tag is relevant though. Stuff like Boolean algebra and De Morgan's Laws etc _might_ be on-topic. Although most of the time such questions probably belong on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: For some reason, this question has a _"Not looking for input"_ closevote, and the _clearly off-topic_ question has 2 undelete-votes... What's going on? This is hardly a controversial closure...

Comment: @Cerbrus The undelete voters probably don't realize that the question will be automatically deleted again anyway should their undeletion succeed, due to being closed and negatively scored.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> Is this question fit for Stack Overflow?

No, because it is not a programming question.

The [discrete-mathematics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discrete-mathematics) tag says:

> Only questions about software development related to discrete mathematics are on topic.

The question does not involve any algorithms or anything related to software development.

Comment: Seems to me, this question is asking for an algorithm, or at least an approach to solving it. In fact, that is what is stated in the first line of the question. So instead of reading "how do I get started solving this", and by default excluding "by programming", suppose that since this is a programming Q & A you just assume "by programming". Now it is indeed a programming question.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy Even when interpreted as an [tag:algorithm] question, it still lacks focus and is unclear.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy Sure, one could add that (and more like which programming language to use ...) and then either edit the question to make it ontopic or post your own question about the topic. As it is, the original creator didn't do that and so most people did not recognize the question as related to programming. I'm sure there are ways to make it related to programming but someone has to do it, otherwise it doesn't count.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy asking for an algorithm is off topic. We want questions that are practical, ie. give me the implementation of this algorithm. Algorithm questions are ok so far as there's something obviously related to programming, either because it's a question about the implementation, or it's a common problem that programmers face.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution asking "which programming language to use" is highly subjective, and likely to turn into a holy war over which language is best, so that is definitely out, but algorithms are at the heart of programming unless you are just mindlessly writing code. granted they are an abstraction and must be implemented but the uncommon problems programmers face are the most interesting questions.

Comment: @Braiam I suppose there is a fine line between asking about an algorithm and asking for an algorithm. Would you also say that asking for a design pattern for a given situation is also off topic?

Comment: @jmarkmurphy Algorithm questions themselves are generally off-topic on Stack Overflow unless they're specifically about a _code/programming implementation_ of said algorithm.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy "is highly subjective" Sorry, I meant it the other (highly objective) way, where the asker specifies what programming language he/she is interested in. I remember vaguely a discussion about whether questions not asking for a specific language are ontopic, but not the details anymore. However, specifying a language typically makes questions ontopic. Only in this case I cannot read the mind of the original creator. If I could do that, I would simply edit that information in but I cannot take the question over (or want to).

Answer (score -22):

This type of questions requires strict logic reasoning, not getting confused, and sometimes creative order of evaluation of your logic. At this level, this is not related to programming. Such puzzles are supposed to be fun for humans, not computer tasks.

However, you could easily convert this puzzle into statements in symbolic boolean logic, and then any programming language could solve it (using symbolic simplification or brute-force search). Maybe not what OP expected, but an answer which used programming would be a very useful tool for anyone who tried to solve such puzzles.

I have just asked ChatGPT this puzzle, and it output a lot of authentic-looking reasoning, which proved to be utter nonsense from logical point of view. This shows another possible application of programming to such puzzles: How would you verify a solution which may contain errors? Convert everything to boolean logic statements and verify each of them! So an answer to OP would be useful for anyone who wanted to do that.

So, in my opinion, you could make an on-topic answer to OP, which kinda makes OP on-topic too.

Comment: You lost me at ChatGPT. What that AI thinks or outputs is _beyond_ irrelevant. And no, being able to formulate an on-topic answer doesn't make an off-topic question on-topic. _"What's the formula for air resistance"_ can be answered with code. That doesn't make it a programming question.

Comment: I wonder if you genuinely disagree with my point on ChatGPT or didn't understand what I wanted to say. I have clarified and expanded my idea. Anyway, you disagree with all the rest of my reasoning, so no chance we can agree; just wondering on that specific part.

Comment: You're making a point there that you could ___apply___ programming to the puzzle. You're basically restating that it _can_ be answered with programming. And again, that doesn't make the question on-topic.

Comment: OK, I already know you disagree with me on this. Nothing new here.

Comment: You're the one that asked me to clarify ;-)

Comment: Now that's thinking outside of the box in order to circumvent well-established rules. I can now answer cooking questions on Stack Overflow, if only I formulate the answer as code generating the recipe!

Comment: @Gimby Just use [Chef](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Chef); recipes are natively supported!

Comment: "*you could make an on-topic answer to OP, which kinda makes OP on-topic too.*" That is not correct. You can write code to do anything a user can do on a computer. That does not make the question "How do I open my web browser", for example, an on-topic question.

Comment: A good answer can transform a bad question into a good question. I have seen it many times here. It doesn't always happen; maybe happens in 1% of cases. My claim is, this can even make an off-topic question on-topic. Let's say in 1% of cases. So your example represents the other 99%. I agree that they exist. The difference between us is you don't believe in the existence of that other 1%, while I do.

Comment: @anatolyg Instead of simply re-stating your opinion, and claiming _"but it __can__ happen"_, your argument would be a _lot_ stronger if you could link to a few examples of it having happened... I'm having a hard time believing it.

Comment: Whether a question is on-topic or not depends entirely on the _question_. Whatever answers may be posted are irrelevant.

Comment: If the question asked is not about programming, twisting an answer into a programming solution does not change the question itself. If the question is off-topic, it's off-topic. The purpose of the guidelines is to keep the noise and clutter down, and finding a convoluted way to keep off-topic questions around is counter-productive.

Comment: If you consider an answer on-topic and good enough so that an off-topic question should stay, **edit** the off-topic question to make it on-topic. Just the presence of the answer won't make the question on-topic.

Comment: @KenWhite While I agree with you in a formal way, I see it in a kind of opposite way: If you have an opportunity to get a valuable answer on how to apply programming to a certain problem, dismissing it because of the way the problem is presented is counter-productive. People who don't know the answer usually can't formulate the question perfectly; sometimes even adequately. If the question is off-topic, edit it so it's on-topic. The purpose of the guidelines is to share valuable programming solutions in the community without clutter getting in the way.

Comment: Simply because you can answer a question with a block of code does not make that an appropriate answer to the question or mean the question is on-topic. An example: OP asks "how do I make the first sentence in my word document a heading?" just because you could provide code that does this doesn't make this question any better/on-topic, at best you are allowing people to skirt the bounds of "SO is not a coding service" and at worst you provided a useless answer to someone who doesn't even know the programming language you wrote your answer in.

Comment: @Nifim SO *is* a coding service.

Comment: @KevinB Sorry i may have been unclear, i mean to say SO is not a place from someone to come and state "i need a program that does XYZ, please write it for me, k thanks" no code of their own or attempt to solve the problem just a requirement and a request that someone do it for them

Comment: @Nifim that's the definition of a "How To" question, which is generally the best style of question that exists on the network in terms of usefulness. The key is it needs to be a thing that can reasonably be handled within an SO Q&A and not be a duplicate. **No attempt is required.**

Comment: @KevinB so it is acceptable to ask "I need a program that writes 50 random words from a provided dictionary"? I can not imagine a day where that question does not receive a bucket of downvotes and close votes.

Comment: No, because that's multiple problems. however it'd be perfectly fine to ask how to randomly select 50 items from an array. ([and it'd be a dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269545/how-to-get-a-number-of-random-elements-from-an-array))

Comment: I think you and I are talking about 2 different users, 1 who is looking for an answer to a question they actual want to learn (your user) and 1 who just wants someone to write some code for them (my user). But sure I can concede that SO is a coding service for your user.