# Why does SO have an UML tag, given that UML is clearly for programmers.SE?

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently some UML tagged questions (e.g. [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/331533/sloppiness-in-activity-diagrams)) have been migrated to Programmers Stack Exchange. According to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254570/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange/254571#254571)

> If it is related to coding, it should be on Stack Overflow.
>
> If it's related to higher level programming concepts or is conceptual (but still related to programming), it should be on Programmers.
>
> Rule of thumb: if you're sitting in front of your IDE, ask it on Stack Overflow. If you're standing in front of a whiteboard, ask it on Programmers.

Now I'm starting to ask myself: what have I been doing all my time answering UML questions on SO rather than PSE? And why is PSE called "programmers" if the target seems more like architects and analysts? I will leave that question out right now.

UML is not about coding in any way (well, almost) but about design. It's definitely totally about standing-in-front-of-the-whiteboard. Ergo: UML has to be discussed on P.SE.

I would not mind too much, but I earned most of my points with UML. Now if things get migrated (is there any plan to migrate certain questions?), am I supposed to start over at almost zero at PSE? Is the UML tag on SO meant in a different way I thought? Should the UML tag on SO be removed?

Confused I am.

Comment: I don’t think *retroactive* mass migrations are that common (and I think reputation that is older than 30 days would stay grandfathered in even if questions got migrated en masse). You’ll just find more and more such questions turning up on P.SE

Comment: The funny thing is that many programmers loathe UML, so putting UML Q and A on a site with that namesake is counter intuitive.

Comment: I fully agree with your doubts. But maybe the question should be - "Should P.SE be renamed to Designers and Architects?". And then of course the UML tag (and all related) should be removed from SO. On the other hand - many uml questions I've seen on SO where tightly related to a code documentation. Do we really want to split those? Finally - some questions related to specific CASE tools (e.g. Enterprise Architect). Do we want to put it on P.SE? SE? Some dedicated new page for resolving problems with applications?

Comment: Programmers is undergoing a name change, will become Software Engineering soon (6-8 weeks?). More details here: [What is this “Software Engineering” site you speak of, and what kinds of questions can I ask there?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/8204/25936)

Comment: @Yannis Ah! That might be the answer. I'll start reading.

Comment: I was sitting in front of my IDE to document the code with UML diagrams, but since [my question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/331641/how-do-i-represent-nested-actions-in-a-uml-activity-diagram) was conceptual it was moved on PSE. I wouldn't mind that much if the points were kept on both sites, but I don't really like that my SO points for this questions are moved to PSE. I've earned these points on SO, not PSE, even though it was maybe an error.

Comment: @TimF Right. I think that the above move noted by Yannis should include a rethinking about UML at all in this context. Sort of a migration - of question and points (as a thought). I think UML is better hosted on that new platform and should be deprecated on SO (I don't think there's much debugging involved with UML modeling).

Comment: There are systems you program in UML, with UML debuggers etc!    (The ones I have used are best forgotten about!)

Comment: @IanRingrose Maybe. But I can't remember a single question about that. Let there be a handful which lie back in the past. In the current context a UML tag on SO does not really make sense then.

Comment: You could say the same about remembering any worthwhile question in the PHP tag!

Comment: "**Be a bit jealous of your site** - don't blithely turn askers away simply because their question could be asked somewhere else. Don’t hit them over the head with your scope, help them tailor their question to fit into it - and if that means your site’s scope overlaps a bit with another site’s, so be it..." ([Respect the community - your own, and others’](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/)) Quick glance over [tag:uml] tag at SO rather strongly suggests that this guidance applies here

Comment: I agree. But UML seems to be a special case. Seeing the scope of both SO and PSE, UML in general should be hosted on PSE (once that naming issue is fixed). Leaves open the question about migration, though.

Comment: @ThomasKilian: migration of questions and reputation points. We may lose most of the capabilities we've earned otherwise.

Comment: Hey. The exact same thing with the [tag:open-source] tag! Don't we have an entire site about it: [Open Source Stack Exchange](https://opensource.stackexchange.com)? :P

Comment: @jpaugh I better should. But then when I hear "ad arma!" I rather like to be prepared :-)

Comment: A lot of the sites have overlapping subjects. UML questions "clearly" fit into the topic definitions of both SO *and* Programmers-soon-to-be-Software-Engineering and I bet I could find a few to stick on Computer Science as well. So you start becoming more active at PSE and start off with no rep. Big deal. That's how everybody starts on a community that they've newly become a part of. Be active there and you'll build it up again. Answer UML questions there, yay. Plus, there's a lot more subjects than just UML to post answers to, you'll be fine.

Comment: UML is a graphical language. It's code is expressed by pictures. If a question/answer includes the UML graphics then it is about `coding` and then it belongs on SO

Answer (score 21):

What if the question is about how to implement the UML concept of inheritance in C#? (According to some UML books, an “object” is allowed to change its type in response to method calls!)

I think I have shown that there are at least some UML questions that can belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have earned most of my points with UML. And I think I can tell that 99% are about concepts. Things you would do on a white board. Now, I could as well have asked "why is Programmers about concepts and should conceptual questions be migrated in any case (not only UML)?". So I pin it to the UML tag where I can tell concept from - hmmm - implementation/debugging.

Comment: @ThomasKilian, but the 1% of UML questions that are not about concepts are skill enough to justifies a UML tag on stackoverlfow.

Comment: @ThomasKilian And lots of tags could be in the same situation actually. Bluetooth-lowenergy, embedded, microcontroller (should go to Electrical Engineering), etc. Just the fact that SO's Tour page excludes "Anything not directly related to writing computer programs" is contradictory with the smartphones' tags (android, swift, ios).

Comment: @TimF Hu. Turns out to be a can of worms.

Comment: How about [language-agnostic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) (1,632 questions) and [design-patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-patterns%20-c%23%20-java%20-c%2b%2b%20-php%20-javascript) (1,034 questions with popular languages tags excluded)?

Comment: @david: UML is a language. (The Unified Modeling Language)

Comment: @JimL I fully agree with Ian that there are at least some UML questions that belog on SO. By mentioning "language-agnostic" and "design-patterns", I'm merely following TimF's list and asking whether these are the types of questions that the SO community feels should be moved to Programmers (soon to be renamed [Software Engineering](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/8204)).

Comment: @DavidRR That's my point too. I just can talk about UML which is a migration-candidate. But the two you point out also look alike. Probably there are some more.

Answer (score 14):

Questions about code *in the context of UML* belong on SO. Some examples:

- errors in code generated from a UML diagram
- understanding the fine detail implications when coding up a UML concept
- how to implement a concurrent process from a UML diagram

Tagging a question with a particular tag doesn't necessarily mean the question is *about* that tag directly; it can also mean that the tag is *relevant* to the question.

---

There is no way to distinguish the concept of a "primary" and a "secondary/related" tag, but that doesn't seem to cause any issues - people can tell in context what/how tags apply. Introducing that distinction would cause problems and generally be a distraction.

Comment: There were actually two recent answers migrated (the one I linked and another similar one which IIRC is linked in some comment). Now, why were these two chosen? I'd say that most of the questions are on a similar level. Would it be possible to hold on with migrating anything before the new PSE has been set up firmly?

Answer (score 9):

Using the same flawed logic, we should then also migrate all questions about object-oriented programming.

TL;DR: you can't have professional coding without program design and you can't have program design without the actual coding in mind.

---

Writing code is intimately related to program design and vice versa. You can't have one of them without the other, or you are not a professional programmer. Anyone who has worked with programming knows this. This isn't subjective, it is just how programming works.

UML questions may very well receive better answers elsewhere. Perhaps they are more suitable for other sites. But since they are program design questions, they cannot be off-topic on a site about professional programming. Just because something is on-topic elsewhere, it doesn't mean that the same thing turns off-topic on SO.

Also, if you don't think program design is about coding, I don't think you understand program design at all. Decisions like what needs to be classes and when to use inheritance, need to be *pragmatic* and make sense in the real-world program. Otherwise you are just creating burdensome overhead.

The program designer needs to keep practical things in mind such as "do I really know enough of the product at this point to dictate an interface?" or "will this design lead to less efficient code". Good program design will consider the strengths and limits of the programming language that will be used.

And of course all good program design is iterative, you will have to tweak the design as you go, when you receive more information or come up with better ideas along the way. It common that you come up with a need to change the program design (or specification) during the implementation phase.

---

All that being said, the Programmers site seems to be going through some existential crisis and I wouldn't recommend anyone to use that site until they fix their internal problems.

Comment: "Writing code is intimately related to program design and vice versa" indeed. But effectively that means a separation of SO and PSE does not make sense, does it?

Comment: @ThomasKilian [separation makes sense to folks like me](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/8062/31260 "as explained here"): "software architecture and design... topics are difficult to find and follow at SO. Given that I am not interested in asking and answering code troubleshooting questions and that my interest in reading these is quite specific and limited, I essentially have no other option but Programmers."

Comment: @gnat The problem with UML is that it actually tries to fill the gap between design and implementation (and other areas). But this way it actually belongs to both worlds. Now the question just seems to be: "which death should I die?".

Comment: @ThomasKilian I have little interest in UML but if I had I'd probably feel comfortable watching respective tags at both sites so to me it is more like two lives to live and not two deaths to die

Comment: @gnat Well, you don't have to fear that you need to start with almost zero reputation on another site. But definitely I see that coming. As what PSE is positioned it's all about UML and SO is nearly nothing. But it hosts all my answers. Now, should I in future propose to move questions to PSE where they are more suited but where I'm a nobody?

Comment: @ThomasKilian let's see... I said I have no interest in UML but I know user who does and who is active at both sites. They have [41 posts](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:4+[uml]) at Programmers and [14 posts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:572+[uml]) here. What I observe suggests that on one hand you may consider paying closer attention to Programmers but on the other hand staying active at SO won't hurt either

Comment: @gnat They look like those I answered on SO. But: 41/14 from him compared to 4491/291 questions on SO/PSE in total is a different picture. Plus some of the 14 look rather like candidates for PSE. My ratio is 709/3.

Comment: @ThomasKilian yeah that why I said staying active at SO won't hurt. Frankly I hate it when folks say that design, architecture, UML are bad fit for SO and I hope this attitude will never get official approval... although it's a Robert Harvey's rant, he seems to hate it even more

Comment: @gnat And to add insult to injury: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/290410/how-to-show-retry-in-sequence-diagram/290411#290411 is an old question which has been migrated to PSE and that's exactly one where I'd say it's SO specific and not about design. Who was talking about sleeping dogs here?

Comment: @ThomasKilian I guess that's the price you pay for the interest in topic that has home at two sites. You wouldn't have this problem if instead you would focus on questions about debugging Java codez but would you want to? :)

Comment: @Lundin: UML is (possibly more) useful for modeling the problem domain. That is a different activity than the design process of the solution domain (e.g., for programming). Many these days skip the analysis of the problem domain, which is one reason so many projects fail.

Answer (score 2):

The UML questions can be roughly divided into:

1. How to express in UML some piece of code
2. How to implement in code something expressed in UML
3. How to express some abstractions in UML
4. How to design something using UML
5. Coding, macros, etc... of UML tools (?)

I think that:

- 1,2 and 5 are obviously related to code and seem to be better kept on SO.
- 4 is better kept on PSE: the answers are longer, the argumentation more abstract.
- 3 is very ambiguous:  putting specifications in some kind of programming language is obviously to code, and UML is a high level language.  However it's also design and often very close of 4.

I guess it will frequently be difficult to make the right choice, and I'm as confused as you. By the way, whiteboards are sometimes replaced by UML tools with a beamer, which only add to the confusion.

The only way out, would be to remove the `uml` tag and replace it with more specific tags such as `uml-documentation`, `implement-uml` and same on PSE.  But this might be to subtle for the average new user trying just to ask his waguely related UML question...

Comment: Yes. As UML supporters we (I'm speaking not just for myself) fell like sitting between the chairs now. Having a Analysts rather than Programmers site will likely help to sort things out. But then we are thrown back to square one.