# Is there a way to make my algorithm/approach question on-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

I asked [Large doubly-linked-list (or other) storage on disk for queue system; options for how to store](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44296220), which was put on hold as off-topic. I've since deleted the question: [image of question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB5mq.jpg).

The original version did clearly contain a line asking for existing software packages that could be used, but I edited to remove it and instead ask for "algorithms or approaches".

From [Choosing between Stack Overflow and Software Engineering](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254570/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-software-engineering), the accepted answer says:

> If it is related to coding or tools, it should be on Stack Overflow.
>
> If it's directly related to the Systems Development Life Cycle (except for troubleshooting, writing or explaining specific code), it should be on Software Engineering.

**My question is essentially "what is a good algorithm/data structure/approach to this specific problem".**  It is true there is no code in the question, which I've seen mentioned as another way to discern, but I do not see that stated in any actual doc pages (if that is a specific requirement, it would be an *excellent* addition to the tour page and I think help a lot).

The [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page lists 6 signs a question might be off-topic, but my question does not meet any of them:

1. debugging help
2. suffering from unreproducability,
3. homework
4. a recommendation for a specific software library or other resource. (It *was* at first, but I removed that part)
5. about general computing hardware or software (I don't fully understand what this means - it's pretty... general; is this supposed to mean "if it doesn't have code in the question"?)
6. about network stuff.

I realize I can just [re-post on Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/350003/large-doubly-linked-list-or-other-storage-on-disk-for-queue-system-options-fo) and I've done that, but I'm honestly trying to understand the rules here (and possibly suggest an improvement to the documentation). Even after 3.5k rep this is still a source of confusion for me.

My specific questions for Meta are: **Which specific point does this question violate and is there a way to rework it so it is valid for SO?**

Comment: IMHO this would be more suitable on CS then SO.

Comment: Questions without code can be on-topic. IMHO, that not the issue, but _"what is a good algorithm/data structure/approach"_ sounds primarily opinion-based...

Comment: Can it be converted to a "How do i do X" question without "X" being "build my app/page/tool for me"? if not, it probably can't be saved.

Comment: @KevinB well what I'm looking for is applicable algorithms.  For example, an answer like "some MQs are implemented using an XYZ data structure and blahdy blah log, blah blah; and this is good because it's a balance between performance and not loosing your data on power loss" - that's the sort of answer I was hoping to evoke.  I'm not asking anyone to write code for me, I'm asking them to briefly describe how they would approach the problem and name techniques used.

Comment: and... that sounds quite a bit broad, if not opinionated.

Comment: Basically... if you come out of the gate showing your existing solution and point out the pitfalls, asking how to solve those problems, you might have a chance. but in this case the pitfalls are due to storage location, not code related problems. i don't think you can make that on topic.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to other sites on the Stack Exchange network. Or, if you do, delete the question on one or the other.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan got it, will clean that up.

Comment: I would argue that your question still met the 4th condition for why it's off-topic, and would fall under "other resource".

Comment: @Kevin B I think we can discuss the tradeoffs of the approaches without it being particularly opinion-based.  Which to pick would tend to be opinion-based, but I disagree that requesting approaches and tradeoffs tends to be opinion-based, and in a lot of cases I don't think it would end up being too broad.

Comment: Yeah, if I knew an answer to this question I could express it in a three or four paragraphs and it would be meaningful.  As is, I don't have enough experience with on-disk data structures, but I disagree that this question would be too broad for a meaningful short answer.

Comment: @AntonH Just so I see the logic, you're saying that naming an algorithm is an off-site resource? While I think you have a point there, it's also worth noting that at least some algorithms are easily explainable in pseudocode right in the answer.  A binary search for example could be named and a bit of code shown as an example.  While not the same, IMO it's quite similar to someone asking how to make an Ajax call w/o jquery and people naming fetch and xmlhttprrequest and providing sample code - the approach along with any needed sample to clarify (or no sample if unneeded)

Comment: Too broad question?

Comment: Asking for something that you've not attempted yourself is off topic or too broad if you've not managed to isolate the problem to a particular resource. I'm struggling to see the image as I'm on my mobile to review the question thoroughly to provide a proper answer.

Comment: @Bugs as foolish as I am for arguing against my own position on this one, I do like how specific your point is when used as a rule: if you haven't tried it yourself then it's not on topic for SO.  Curious if that's covered in any rule/guideline doc you know of?

Comment: FYI: It's usually better to retain a link to the SO question, so anyone with >10k rep can view the deleted question (I've edited it back in). Please move the question's image to the Stack Exchange image hosting (i.e. where it would be if you used the normal add-image dialog while editing the question). A) As much as possible, questions should not rely on external resources, which may go away (just like questions anywhere on SE). B) Hosting an image on an external site potentially makes it more difficult for people to see it. Users will already have set up the ability to view SE hosted images.

Comment: @Makyen thanks will fix soon on the image.  Got it on the deletion, did that because I re-asked on se.SE, but I get your point.

Comment: @Bugs, Your statement has a qualifier "if you've not managed to isolate the problem to a particular resource", which is unclear (but potentially valid). Questions are *not* inherently off-topic if the person has not attempted to solve it, but are *often* off-topic due to being too broad. An attempt to solve a problem usually helps to narrow the focus of the problem to one which is answerable in the SO format (i.e. actually has an answer, not a discussion/exploration of all possible answers).

Comment: IMO, the stated reason for the question (Q) being on hold is incorrect for the *current* rev. of the Q. Currently, the Q is too broad, as it does not give enough information for a solution. It would require someone to make lots of assumptions in order to determine a good way to accomplish the task. The Q is basically asking for a *discussion* of all possible ways to accomplish something, which is significantly too broad for SO. The votes to close as a off-site resource request were, probably, from the first 3 versions of the Q, which asked for "any existing open source projects".

Comment: Not isolating the problem to a particular resource _is_ off topic as you're asking for someone to recommend one. If you have but not attempted it, it _may_ be too broad as you're asking for someone to start without actually knowing where to start. I don't think it's covered in a particular doc but comes down to those 5 that have voted to close. I'd happily take a look over the question to provide exacts as I've had a busy day and I'm struggling to remember/see the question.

Comment: @Makyen that makes a lot of sense to me. I can't see the question so I'm struggling to provide exacts but that sums it up.

Comment: You list the reasons why it might be off topic, but none of what it makes on topic, namely: a practical, answerable problem that is **unique to software development**.

Comment: Revisiting this to read over the question again and I can see now why I was happy enough to cast my vote.  _Curious what algorithms or approaches exist that are already tailored to this problem_ still makes it a request for resource IMO and therefore this question is still off topic.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite it:

- inserting your design and package decisions. Identify specific data structures in specific packages
- in order to reduce subjectivity, state what your design criteria are: compatibility with XYZ, simplicity, performance etc.
- remove any language that could be construed as calling for discussion or recommendation. Like never say "Options for storing...". Call it "Data structure for storing..." or just "Storing..."
- esp. delete the following phrase which is like a red rag to the subjective/question-too-broad/recommendation camp:

> *Curious what algorithms or approaches exist that are already tailored to this problem.*

- identify a few yourself and state how good/bad you understand them to be for your purpose
- any question where the OP's choice of packages/ data-structures/ classes could be disagreed with, might *implicitly* be asking for recommendations. There's just this silly pretence on SO that we can't explicitly ask for that (because that opens the floodgates to VLQ and lazy write-my-code-for-me). Best to post token design choices then see how people react. There will still be some that close-war it.