# What is the best way to determine where to ask the question?

Tags: discussion

Let me begin by admitting that this may sound like a really dumb question but I believe it has merit if you bear with me.

As we know, there many "specialized" SE communities that deal with a particular subject in more detail than the main StackOverflow. Most people tend to just ask it there and it either gets moved by the mods or just sits there which in effect fragments the information a bit.

Say you have a programming question, there are several places you can ask it and each one deals with some degree of specialty with the subject. I have noticed that most will ask on SO because they feel it has a higher likelihood of getting answered as it has the most eyes on it.

I myself have found questions asked in specialized communities to go unanswered while reviewing questions in SO find that similar questions are asked on SO and often get quite a few answers and relatively quickly.

- So what is the metric to decide, ask in SO or in some SE instead?
- What rule of thumb should be used to determine where to ask it?
- Should we ask in SO and if need be gets moved later?
- How would that affect answers by those who are say not on the subsequent SE?

Comment: See [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/318307) on MSE. Also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254570/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-software-engineering

Comment: @AndrewMyers that was an example, not all subject fit neatly into that question you linked, but thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Meta Stack Exchange](//meta.stackexchange.com) is best suited for a site recommendation based on a set of explained criteria.

In fact, the tag [`site-recommendation`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) currently has 1721 questions in it.

So, go there, tag your question as [`support`] and [`site-recommendation`], formulate your question, and post it. There are a lot of sites in the exchange, but you should get an answer.

As for whether or not you should just default to Stack Overflow for questions, this may be a bad choice depending on the type of question. If you have a specific programming question that is answerable and reasonably scoped it will go well, but if you repeatedly ask questions which do not fit Stack Overflow and they get migrated away to other exchanges, it is possible that you will begin to have your ability to post questions rate limited.

Looking at your question history, you seem to have made good choices thus far.

Comment: That's why I asked, for clarity, I wasn't aware there is a place for such requests. I also did search and wasn't aware of any duplicates in the sense that I wasn't asking where to ask per se, as I can use common sense that while say you can ask about WP on SO, probably should ask on WP SE instead, it was more of a general understanding of what qualifies for a SE and what goes on SO because frankly there are TONS of overlap without a clear demarcation on why.

Comment: As far as my history, you are correct that I do my due diligence to try and respect the segregation of topics but as I explained, sometimes find myself wondering if perhaps SO would have gotten better results or answers in general. However, on principle, I still avoid dumping all my questions on SO for sake of integrity in making an effort to keep it relevant to the topic. Thanks for the feedback, I will take a more detailed look at the resources linked.

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ - To be honest, sometimes it is a tossup. There aren't really clear guidelines for which one will work best if there is a decent amount of overlap. Assuming the question is on topic in both places, just go with whichever one you feel will yield the best results. Often though, in the on topic section of the smaller exchange there is a description of what the preference is when there is overlap. If the question is on topic and fits at one of the exchanges though, and is well received, it would be very surprising to see it forced off.

Comment: For sake of argument, can you help me with with this hypothetical. You have a question about `powershell` be it syntax, script or whatnot. Where would you put this? PowerUser SE? Programming? InfoSec SE (for scripts that are say security or policy related)? Etc. The reason I ask is that PS can be used in the context of A LOT of things, but when you need help with it, should you ask in general area like SO where PS is covered entirely? or do you ask in specific SE where you are using it? The technical knowledge of PS under a SE where it might be used doesn't have the same parity sometimes.

Comment: Agreed, it is a tossup sometimes but the aggressive smack down by which you are greeted when that toss up goes against some random mod's mood is what I am trying to avoid to be honest. Sometimes the hateful "get of my sandbox"-esqe response you get just makes it discouraging and demoralizing to even bother asking. But thank you, I guess I will have to just do what I have been doing and take my best guess and go with it. When I encounter the less than welcoming behavior, yes for being on topic with the rules set forth but not enforced to the letter by even mods; then just delete it and move on.

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ - I would suggest going to the exchange where the solution or answer matches. If the answer is related to the security concerns of a script, then InfoSec may work. If related to composing the structure that the script will work with then programming. If related to a script that was written but just isn't working, or does something unexpected, then Stack Overflow. Focus more on the group of people answering, and try to picture where the answer would be the best fit.

Comment: Thank you, that is probably the best explanation someone has given to me and aligns with what I was thinking but wasn't sure is how we should decide. I appreciate it, thank you for taking the time.